# JQuery partly triggered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm a beginner with JQuery and I was trying to create a button that dynamically changes the colors defined in the CSS depending on what color it is right now (just switch between blue / red) and also change the text on the button.

The `.draggable()` part executes just fine and so does the first and last console.log, so everything but the part within the click event handler works ... but why?

Relevant html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Meine Website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
            type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"
            type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="home_jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="home_javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home_style_blau.css">

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="farbwechsel_button" value="Rot" />
/* rest of html (taschenrechner_box, etc.) */
</body>
```

Here's the jQuery part:

```
var blau = true;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#taschenrechner_box').draggable();


    console.log("test1");
    $('#farbwechsel_button').click(function() {
        console.log("test2");


        if (blau == true) {
            console.log("blau = " + blau);
            $('body').css({"background-color": "8b0000"});
            $('#farbwechsel_button').value = "Blau";
            blau = false;
        }
        else {
            console.log("blau = " + blau);
            $('body').css({"background-color": "lightsteelblue"});
            $('#farbwechsel_button').value = "Rot";
            blau = true;
        }
        console.log("test3");

    })
    console.log("test4");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML you have:

```
<input type="button" id="farbwechsel_button" value="Rot" />
```

But in your JS you refer to

```
$('#farbwechel_button').click(function() {
```

Note the forgotten **s** in your JS. So the JS should be:

```
$('#farbwechsel_button').click(function() {
```

Edit: you've forgotten the **s** in al your referrals to the button. Don't forget to add it everywhere. You've also forgotten a `;` just before the last `console.log()` function.

Edit 2: Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zc447/)** with a working example. It's pretty much self explanatory. In this case you preferably should make use of classes which you toggle on pressing the button.

Comment: Thanks! Checked for stuff like that a hundred times, but I guess a second pair of eyes doesn't hurt :/ Still doesn't work though ...?

Comment: The code inside the `click` function still isn't executing? Are you getting any errors in your console? Or just nothing?

Comment: You've forgotten a `;` in the line before `console.log("test4");` and also when checking for the value `blau` you can just use `if (blau)` instead of `if (blau == true)`.

Comment: Okay thanks! Also found my mistake. I need a # before the rgb value and somehow (saw it in some examples I think) the "lightsteelblue" doesn't work either. Now I just need to change the button but that's not so important. Thank youuu!

Comment: The button can be changed by setting the `val` value. Where you now have `$('#farbwechsel_button').value = "Blau";` it should read `$('#farbwechsel_button').val("Blau");`. You can get the current value of the button by doing this: `var color = $('#farbwechsel_button').val();`.